# fig.update_layout does not update layout in python plotly

Tags: python, plotly

`x_edges` and `y_edges` are values between -6 and 6, but when I show the figure the axis range from 0 to 50 (which is the size of the arrays x_edges and y_edges).

```
df = pd.DataFrame(h, index=x_bins_centers, columns=y_bins_centers)
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(z=df)])
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis = dict(
        tickmode = 'array',
        tickvals = x_edges,
        ticktext = x_edges
    ),
    yaxis = dict(
        tickmode = 'array',
        tickvals = y_edges,
        ticktext = y_edges
    )
)
fig.show()
```

`df` is pandas data frame where index is `x_edges` and columns are `y_edges`

Plot can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZB3y.jpg). I am executing this code on Google Colab.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mind to provide a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: I have added a plot

Comment: Please add all your code.

Comment: That is it, there is nothing else relevant

Comment: do you mind to add `df`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I solved the problem by defining figure as:
`fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(x=x_bins_centers, y=y_bins_centers, z=h)])`